# Displaying highest value in high chart (on pie chart)

Tags: highcharts

How to display the highest value and also show the untested values in pie chart?

[Please check the url for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvlYH.png)

All helps are appreciated.

Comment: You should include the code you've got so far, maybe even in a JSFiddle or similar so people can try to solve your problem in a real environment.

Comment: Hi halvor strand,thanks for your reply,please check this url https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvlYH.png , in this url i have mentioned one arrow mark,i need to get that option in my project.
if any default option is available to achieve that one.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Chart.renderer()` function to add a custom text to a chart. Take a look at the example I prepared for you.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.text
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0k86pb18/

Comment: Hi man,really thanks for your help,this what i want,can you please mentioned the untested values too.it would be great full to me.

Comment: The principle is the same. If you want to add something more, simply extend string used in the renderer.text() function. Btw. I wonder why someone gave me -1, as the answer lives up to the requirements.